# codeigniter, bootstrap

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

i have the following folder structure

```
application
assets\
      \css
      \js
      \images
```

i have all the bootstrap files in the assets folder - css files in the css folder, js files in js folder etc. 
My question is this.  I have a view that uses the bootstrap.css.  I reference it by doing something like:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" scr=<?php base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap.css>    </script>
```

it find the file just fine.  but when i try to use the built in images in bootstrap, they don't display because the bootstrap css is expecting the images to be in

```
       "../img/glyphicons-halfing.png"
```

But the physical path of the view is something like:

c:\wamp\www\myapp\views\templates\

I guess I could just copy the image folder into the views folder... or i can edit the css to point to the right location.  But i just wanted to check to see how others are organizing their folders using codeigniter and bootstrap. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking in 'img' - You need to amend it to 'images'

```
"../images/glyphicons-halfing.png"
```

Comment: thanks, but i already figured out the problem.  just wondering why my answer was deleted? i apologize for posting the original question... sometimes it takes "talking" through something to pick up on mistakes!  anyways.  thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicons goes inside the "assets\font" folder.

Just in case, I'm using CodeIgniter 3.x and Xampp 5.6.x on xubuntu.

```
assets\
      \css\
      \js\
      \images\
      \fonts\
             glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
             glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```